# How can I use log4net in WF4?

Tags: log4net, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4, consoleappender

I've created a simple WF4 console app and set up log4net identically to my other apps. However, when I fire up the console and use the `ILog` object inside WF4 (I actually pass it into the workflow), no information is presented using my `ColoredConsoleAppender`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have a .Net 4 app that works with log4net? Based on some questions here, you would think that there might be problems with .Net 4 in general...

Comment: Yes, I have multiple .Net 4 apps (e.g., windows services) that use log4net just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Workflow trace output is written to trace listeners and as far as I am aware log4net doesn't log the output written to a trace listener by default. I am no expert on log4net so there might be an easier way but creating a TraceListener that just passes all data on to log4net is not hard, the following code worked just fine in a quick test.

```
public class Log4netTraceListener : TraceListener
{
    private static readonly ILog _log = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

    public override void TraceData(TraceEventCache eventCache, string source, TraceEventType eventType, int id, params object[] data)
    {
        base.TraceData(eventCache, source, eventType, id, data);
    }

    public override void TraceData(TraceEventCache eventCache, string source, TraceEventType eventType, int id, object data)
    {
        var logger = LogManager.GetLogger(source);
        switch (eventType)
        {
            case TraceEventType.Critical:
                logger.Fatal(data);
                break;
            case TraceEventType.Error:
                logger.Error(data);
                break;
            case TraceEventType.Information:
                logger.Info(data);
                break;
            case TraceEventType.Verbose:
                logger.Debug(data);
                break;
            case TraceEventType.Warning:
                logger.Warn(data);
                break;
            default:
                base.TraceData(eventCache, source, eventType, id, data);
                break;
        }
    }

    public override void Write(string message)
    {
        _log.Info(message);
    }

    public override void WriteLine(string message)
    {
        _log.Info(message);
    }
```

Next you need to make sure the activity trace information is send to this TraceListener using the following code in you app.config.

```
<system.diagnostics>
  <sources>
    <source name="System.Activities"
            switchValue="Verbose">
      <listeners>
        <add name="Test"
              type="WorkflowConsoleApplication17.Log4netTraceListener, WorkflowConsoleApplication17"/>
      </listeners>
    </source>
  </sources>
</system.diagnostics>
```

Comment: Thanks for that! But the problem I face is that I'm using an `ILog` right in the workflow and the output doesn't appear in my console.

Comment: If you load your logger inside of a workflow you need to specify the assembly to use. Something like: log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly(), "System.Activities"). If you only specify a name it will try to load the configuration of a dynamic assembly and won't find anything.

Answer (score 3):

[Create an Extension](http://www.infinitec.de/post/2009/10/20/Workflow-Foundation-4-e28093-Part-II-NativeActivities-and-Extensions.aspx) for your workflow that your activities can get from the context.

```
var wf = new WorkflowApplication(myActivity);
var log = new MyLogForNetExtensionLol();
wf.Extensions.Add(log);
```

then, within the activity:

```
var log = context.GetExtension<ILog>();
log.Write("Worked!");
```